# PGPy won't go on GCP Dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, python-3.8

I'm trying to use PGPy library in a custom GCP Dataflow pipeline implemented with Apache Beam.
What I get is that everything works with DirectRunner, but when I deploy the job and execute it on DataflowRunner I get an error on PGPy usage:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pgpy'

I think I'm missing something with DataflowRunner.

Thank you

Comment: I need to encrypt with PGP a file created during dataflow job execution

Comment: was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to manage pipeline dependencies please refer to :

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/

My personal preference is to go straight to using setup.py as it lets you deal with multiple file dependencies, which tends to get used once the pipeline gets more complex.